# grequests - too many open files error

Tags: python, grequests

I'm trying to perform about 100k GET requests and parse the response body of each request. I thought grequests would be a good way to go, but I'm getting errors related to 'too many open files'. Here's the code:

```
import grequests

with open("./100k-sites.csv", "r") as f:
    urls = ["http://" + line.rstrip() for line in f]

rs = (grequests.get(u, timeout=1) for u in urls)
responses = grequests.map(rs)

for r in responses:
    try:
        # do something with the response body
    except:
        pass
```

anyone got experience with this? The error I'm getting is:

> requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at
>   0x7f817ab36898>: Failed to establish a new connection [Errno 24] Too
>   many open files

Comment: There's a rather [long discussion](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/239) on Github, though without a real fix as far as I can see.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it's only a workaround (as somebody in the [discussion](https://github.com/requests/requests/issues/239) mentioned above says), but IMHO it's worth of writing here, that one can fix it by the two lines:

```
import resource
resource.setrlimit(resource.RLIMIT_NOFILE, (110000, 110000))
```

Answer (score -1):

Use imap instead of map

```
for resp in grequests.imap(rs, size=20):
    pass
```

and then you will not have such problems with processes and memory. but keep in mind that imap returns a generator